# Getting location to resources folder in intellij

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have little problem with Intellij. I tried to create a simple application in Java and Spring using maven in Intellij. My project structure looks like this:

```
MyProject:
|--src
|  |--main
|  |   |--java
|  |   |--resources
|  |   |--web
|  |   |   |--WEB-INF
|  |   |   |   |--dispatcher-servlet.xml
|  |   |   |   |--web.xml
|  |--test
```

The problem is when i try add to `dispatcher-servlet.xml` line :

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

My intellij dont see the folder resources, only `WEB-INF`. I created project like this:

1. Create project with maven
2. Open module structure
3. Add new module - web application

How can I get access form `dispathcer-servlet.xml` to `resoucres` folder? Or did I use wrong project structure?

Comment: `location="/resources/` does not mean `src/main/resources`. It's actually `src/main/resources/resources`.

Comment: Nothing work, even when i paste my whole path from disc to folder resources like (`location="E:/Java/MyProject/src/main/resources"`)

Comment: What do you mean by `My intellij dont see the folder resources`?

Comment: When i type `location=""` Intellij gives show suggestion on right location, and ony what i'm getting is folder WEB-INF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

That line means:

for every HTTP request with a path starting by `/resources`, go look for the file under the location `/resources/` in the deployed webapp.

You don't have any folder named resources in your webapp. All you have is a src/main/resources in your **Maven project structure**. The files there end up in the classpath (i.e. under WEB-INF/classes in the webapp), as per Maven's conventions.

So, create a resources folder under webapp, or put your files under `src/main/resources/foo` and configure Spring to look for resources in the classpath, under `foo`:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/foo/" />
```

Comment: Can say more about classpath, what is for, how it use and especially why this isnt working `location = "classpath:/resources/"`

Comment: If intellij does not suggest something, it does not mean that your configuration won't work. Put something in `src/main/resources/resources`  or `WEB-INF/resources` directory, say `all.css`, then you can access that file through `localhost:8080/resources/all.css`

Comment: Java is able to load classes using a ClassLoader. A ClassLoader looks for classes in specific locations. Each webapp has its own classloader, which loads classes from WEB-INF/classes and all the jars directly under WEB-INF/lib. That is specified by the servlet specifications. When Maven builds a webapp, it compiles all the Java files under src/main/java into .class files that end up in WEB-INF/classes, and copies all the files under src/main/resources to WEB-INF/classes as well. So these files are loadable by the class loader too.

Comment: `classpath:/resources/` doesn't work, because you don't have any `resources` folder under `src/main/resources`.